# Java, how to add one object to an ArrayList and decrease one from another

Tags: java

I got my exam tomorrow and I have tried to make code that is supposed to be like a store.

I'm satisfied with my code, but I'm missing something. I have made ArrayList with the name `lagerplass`and `handlekurv`. The ArrayList `lagerplass` is supposed to be like a storage for items in a store, and the ArrayList `handlekurv` is supposed to be the items customers is wanting to buy. And this is the problem, I want to find a good way so that when people take items from the store and it goes into `handlekurv` it will decrease the items in `lagerplass`, also that u cannot take items into `handlekurv` without items being in `lagerplass` would love if someone could help me do this with either changing some methods or adding some!

Here is the code for Varer:

```
public class Varer
{
// Representerer merke og pris til en vare.
private String vare; // Representerer selve varen
private String merke; // Representerer merket som er satt fast til Razor
private int pris; // Representerer prisen til varen
private String varenavn; // Representerer varenavnet altså : Naga, Mamba, Kraken osv.

/**
 * Constructor for klassen Varer
 */
public Varer(int pris, String varenavn, String vare)
{
    merke = "Razor";
    this.pris = pris;
    this.varenavn = varenavn;
    this.vare = vare;

}

/**
 * Returner merket
 * @return merke
 */
public String getMerke()
{
    return merke;
}
/**
 * Returnerer pris
 * @return pris
 */
public int getPris() 
{
    return pris;
}
/**
 * Returnerer varenavn altså: Kraken, Tiamat, Naga osv.
 * @return varenavn
 */
public String getVarenavn()
{
    return varenavn;
}
/**
 * Returner selve varen
 * @return vare
 */
public String getVare()
{
    return vare;
}
/**
 * Returnerer alle detailjene til varen
 * @return vare, merke, varenavn, pris
 */
public String getDetails()
{
    return vare + ", " + merke + " " + varenavn + ", " + pris + " kr.";
}
/**
 * Returnerer alle detailjene til varen
 */
public void printDetails()
{
    System.out.println(vare + ", " + merke + " " + varenavn + ", " + pris + " kr.");
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

Here is the code for Handlekurv:

```
public class Handlekurv
{
//Opretter en liste med variablet Varer og objektet handlekurv
public ArrayList<Varer> handlekurv;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Handlekurv
 */
public Handlekurv()
{
    // Lager en ArrayList med variabelen varer
    handlekurv = new ArrayList<Varer>();
}

/**
 * Metode for å legge til varer i Handlekurven!
 * @see Varer
 */
public void addVarer(Varer vare)
{
    handlekurv.add(vare);
}
/**
 * Denne metoden printer ut hva du har i handlekurven
 * @see Varer
 */
public void printHandlekurv()
{
    for (Varer a : handlekurv)
    {
        System.out.println (a.getDetails());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
/**
 * Fjerner alt i handlekurven
 *@see Varer
 */
public void fjernHeleHandlekurv()
{
    handlekurv.clear();
}
/**
 * Returnerer størelsen av listen
 */
public int handlekurvSize()
{
    return handlekurv.size();
}
/**
 * Fjerner spesifikke varer i handlekurven
 * @see Varer
 */
public void fjernEnkeltHandlekurv(String fjernHandlekurv)
{
    Iterator<Varer> it = handlekurv.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Varer t = it.next();
        String varenavn = t.getVarenavn();
        if (varenavn.equals(fjernHandlekurv)) {
            it.remove();
            System.out.println("Du har fjernet: " + fjernHandlekurv+" " + "fra handlekurven din");
        }
    }
}
```

}

And here is the code for Butikk:

```
public class Butikk
{
// Lager en ArrayList med variablen Varer
public ArrayList<Varer> lagerplass;
Handlekurv hk = new Handlekurv();

/**
 * Constructor for klassen Butikk, oppretter ny ArrayList av variablen Varer
 */
public Butikk()
{

    lagerplass = new ArrayList<Varer>();
}

/**
 * Opretter et nye headset og legger denne i lagerplass listen
 * @parm lyd, vare, pris, varenavn
 */
public void nyHeadset(String lyd, String vare, int pris, String varenavn )
{

    Headset nyHeadset = new Headset ( lyd, vare, pris, varenavn);
    lagerplass.add(nyHeadset);

}
/**
 * Opretter et nye mus og legger denne i lagerplass listen
 * @parm vare, pris, varenavn, dpi
 */
public void nyMus(String vare, int pris, String varenavn, int dpi)
{
    Mus nyMus = new Mus(vare, pris, varenavn, dpi);
    lagerplass.add(nyMus);
}
/**
 * Printer ut alle varene i lagerplass listen
 *@see Varer klassen og metoden printDetails
 */
public void printLagerplass()
{
    for (Varer vare : lagerplass)
    {
        vare.printDetails();
    }
}

/**
 * Fjerner alt i lagerplass listen
 */
public void fjernHeleLagerplass()
{
    lagerplass.clear();
}
/**
 * Legger til en vare fra lagerplass til handlekurv
 * @see klassen Varer og metoden getVarenavn
 * @see klassen Handlekurv og metoden addVarer
 */
public void leggTilHandlekurv(String varenavn)
{
    for (Varer a : lagerplass) 
    {
        if (a.getVarenavn().equals(varenavn))
        {
            hk.addVarer(a);
        }
    }
}
/**
 * Printer ut alt i handlekurv listen
 */
public void printHeleHandlekurven()
{
    hk.printHandlekurv();
}
/**
 * Fjerner alt i handlekurv listen
 */
public void FjernHeleHandlekurven()
{
    hk.fjernHeleHandlekurv();
}
/**
 * En metode for å fjerne en enkelt vare fra lagerplass listen.
 */
public void FjernEnkeltVarer(String fjernVarenavn)
{
    Iterator<Varer> it = lagerplass.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        Varer vare = it.next();
        String varenavn = vare.getVarenavn();
        if (varenavn.equals(fjernVarenavn))
        {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
}

 public void fjernEnkeltHandlekurv(String fjernHandlekurv)
{
    hk.fjernEnkeltHandlekurv(fjernHandlekurv);

}
```

}

Comment: What did you try? And why didn't it work?

Comment: @Ryan
I tried using this method:
public void leggTilHandlekurv(String varenavn) { 
    Iterator<Varer> iterator = lagerplass.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
         Varer a = iterator.next();
         if (a.getVarenavn().equals(varenavn)) {
             iterator.remove();
             hk.addVarer(a);
         }
    }
} But this diddnt work, I got an error message when I tried to use my printHeleHandlekurven method and printLagerplass method

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
public class Butikk {

  ...

  /**
   * ...
   *
   * @return found
   */
  public boolean leggTilHandlekurv(String varenavn) {
     for (Varer a : lagerplass) {
        if (a.getVarenavn().equals(varenavn)) {
            lagerplass.remove(a);
            hk.addVarer(a);
            return true;
        }
     }
     return false;
  }

  ...

}
```

If you are searching for products mainly through their name, then I would use a `HashMap<String, Varer>` with name as key to store the products.

Comment: I get an bolean error using this method: The operator you are using here cannot be used for the type of value that you are using it for. You are either using the wrong type here, or the wrong operator.
Ugh... :/

Comment: @KennethRønning It only works that way if you remove by index. Corrected.

Comment: This works! If im not to picky, I just added a lagerplass.size method, so is it possible to return that the item was not there with an else method? And how would u proceed that?

Comment: @KennethRønning you can use it like that to handle if you didn't find it: `if (!legTilHandlekurv("product")) { System.out.println("product not found");} else { // proceed normally }`

Comment: I want it to display something on the screen other than true or false, with usage of System.out.println("You have succeeded in removing " + varenavn );
Sorry for asking you this many times! And thank you for your time, really stressed out with exam tomorrow!

Comment: @KennethRønning then it would be best to throw an Exception if you don't find the product and call the function in a try-catch-block. The simpler but uglier approach is (if you never have null): return a Varer instead of a boolean (return true --> return a, return false --> return null) and check for null, you will have all the information from the Varer.

Comment: @KennethRønning or much simpler, take the function as in my answer and just retrieve the last element from hk (if it was found).

Comment: Sorry im really tired being coding this for about 10 hours, i`m new at coding so I wouldnt know how to do this(?)

Comment: @KennethRønning I see you don't have any methods to retrieve Varer, you could add getVarer(String ...) then you could also simplify legTilHandlekurv (but only works if you have unique product names) or getVarer(int index) or getLastVarer()... and then call one of those methods to get the last element, you probably should add those methods to Handlekurv and to Butikk you can add getHandlekurv, then you can get the last element like this for example butikk.getHandleKurv().getVarer(butikk.getHandlekurv().getSize() - 1);

Comment: Thank you for your patience and help, I think I will just go for this for now and explain tomorrow how I would do this differently, I just got no power left to enforce this. Wish me luck :)

Comment: @KennethRønning good luck ;-) the problem is that there are various ways of doing it, the differences are subtle, but to know which is best, we need to know things like if the product names are unique.